# How to add two vectors together to get a list in R

Tags: r, list, addition

I am attempting to add two vectors together. How do I return all results of a vector added to another vector in list format? Like so:

```
a = c(1:4)
b = c(5:8)
```

where expected result is the following list resulted from `a+b`:

```
list(c(6,7,8,9),
     c(7,8,9,10),
     c(8,9,10,11),
     c(9,10,11,12))

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  8  9 10 11
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- c(1:4)
b <- c(5:8)

lapply(a, function(x){x+b})
```

Comment: Or just ```lapply(a, `+`, b)```

Answer (score 1):

We could compile a small Rcpp function for this.

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
+   #include <Rcpp.h>
+   using namespace Rcpp;
+   // [[Rcpp::export]]
+   Rcpp::List addv(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
+     int alen = a.size();
+     Rcpp::List l(alen);
+     for (int i = 0; i < alen; i++) {
+         l(i) = b + a[i];
+     }
+     return l;
+   }
+ ')
> addv(a, b)
[[1]]
[1] 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1]  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 11

[[4]]
[1]  9 10 11 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 5:8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```r
asplit(outer(a, b, `+`), 1)
[[1]]
[1] 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1]  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 11

[[4]]
[1]  9 10 11 12
```